# Creating a custom control that is a Button that also has a Items and ItemsSource?

Tags: c#, wpf, button, itemssource

I'm trying to create a `SplitButton` control that uses a `ContextMenu` to display its items. The `SplitButton` is currently deriving from `Button`. I have a `PART_DropDownInitiator` that is the little icon the user clicks on to bring up the `ContextMenu` for the `SplitButton` to show its items.

The problem is that I'm trying to setup a default `ContextMenu` inside of the `SplitButton`'s `Template` or style, this way the user of the control doesn't have to do it themselves. At first I figured I'd just have the user just set the `SplitButton.ContextMenu.Items` property in xaml, but that doesn't appear to be possible. Now I'd like to add an `Items` and `ItemsSource` properties to the `SplitButton` that the `ContextMenu` within the `SplitButton`'s template can bind to it. And the user should than just have to set the `Items` or `ItemsSource` property in xaml or code-behind on the `SplitButton`...

But, both the `Items` and `ItemsSource` properties seem to originate from `ItemsControl`, which is a problem because the `SplitButton` is already deriving from `Button`. So I'm not sure what to do... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going the inheritance route, you should derive from HeaderedItemsControl instead, where your default ControlTemplate puts the Header content as the contents of a Button.

As a result, you also get Items/ItemsSource -- the only thing you have to develop is your ControlTemplate.

Lastly, consider implementing the menu portion as a Popup instead of a ContextMenu.  ContextMenu's are a purpose-specific UI element (and generally brought up with a right-click).  For more information, see the default ControlTemplate of ComboBox in aero.normalcolor.xaml.